# Julia: Generating Multidimensional Arrays by Broadcasting/Dot Operations on Vectors

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

I am trying to use broadcasting to store the value of function into a three-dimensional array. Below I use a simple example to illustrate what I am trying to do.

Let's say we have a function `f` that returns a value from three input values and three vectors `X`, `Y` and `Z` that store the input values:

```
f = (x, y, z)-> x^2+y^2+z^2
X, Y, Z = randn(100), randn(100), randn(100)
```

To evaluate `f` over all possible combinations of the values stored in the three vectors `X`, `Y` and `Z`, and then store the results in a three-dimensional array, we can do as follows:

```
[f(x,y,z) for x in X, y in Y, z in Z]
```

However, I want to avoid using for loops and use dot operators or broadcasting instead. So, I write the following:

```
broadcast(z->f.(X, Y', z), Z)
```

However, the problem with it is that the result becomes a one-dimensional array of two-dimensional arrays.

Is there an efficient way to evaluate `f`  over all possible combinations of the values stored in vectors `X`, `Y` and `Z` and put the results in a three dimensional array without using for loops?

I don't want to use for loops because I am considering to put my code on GPUs in the future and it seems that GPU computing does not work well with for loops.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest is to add a third dimension to `Z`, e.g.:

```
f.(X,Y',reshape(Z, 1, 1, 100))
```

or directly generate data of appropriate dimensions:

```
X, Y, Z = randn(100), randn(1,100), randn(1,1,100)
f.(X,Y,Z)
```